# javascript fetch api, why response.json() returns javascript object (instead of JSON string)?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I understand Body.json() is a function that reads the response stream to completion and parses the response **as json**. But when I console.log jsonData after calling json() on the response, I get a javascript object. Shouldn't the jsonData return a json string rather than a javascript object, since we have yet to call JSON.parse() to convert the json data into a JavaScript object.

```
function fetchData() {
  fetch(`https://sv443.net/jokeapi/v2/joke/Any?type=single&idRange=${id}`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((jsonData) => {setJoke(jsonData);console.log(jsonData)});
}
```

***console log Output**:*

{category: "Programming",jokeType: "single"}

***console log Expected output**:*

{"category": "Programming","jokeType": "single"}

Comment: Because that is what the spec states? It is a request to treat the response as if it was JSON and parses it for you. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json

Answer (score 4):

"Parsing as JSON" means that it treats the response as if it were JSON and parses it (which converts it into a JavaScript data structure).

It **doesn't** mean it stringifies it **to** JSON (which would be the opposite, and (in this case) also pointless: it is *already* JSON).

If you want the raw JSON from the response then read it as text with the `text()` method.

Answer (score 0):

The `JSON()` method of the Response interface takes a Response stream and reads it to completion. It returns a promise which resolves with the result of parsing the body text as JSON.

Note that despite the method being named `JSON()`, the result is not JSON but is instead the result of taking JSON as input and parsing it to produce a JavaScript object.

[Mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json)